# SQL Stored Procedure Division rounding with decimals

Tags: sql

I have created a simple stored procedure for division.  When I run it, it rounds the numbers even though they are decimals.  For instance, `5.0/10.0=1`. Why does it do this?

Here is the script:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE uspDivide2Numbers2
     @intValue1 AS DECIMAL
    ,@intValue2 AS DECIMAL
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON      --Report only errors

DECLARE @intResult AS DECIMAL = 0

--Do calculation
SELECT @intResult = @intValue1 / @intValue2

--Display results
SELECT @intResult AS intResult

GO

uspDivide2Numbers2 5.0, 10.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not defined scale for DECIMAL datatype.

Declare your stored procedure parameters with scale specified.

```
  @intValue1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)
    ,@intValue2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)
```

and

```
DECLARE @intResult AS DECIMAL(10,2)
```

This means @intResult can have two digits after decimal point (i.e. scale =2 ) and maximum 10 digits.
If you don't define the scale , sql assumes scale =0 and hence you won't get digits after decimal point.

Comment: Actually, in your example the precision is 10 and 2 is the scale. The scale is the number of digits stored to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: OMG ! sorry .. let me change